# Python on HPC (suse linux) without root (install problems)

Tags: python, linux, installation, suse

I'm trying to install my own version of python on an HPC without root access so I can use my own packages. So far I am banging my head against the wall and getting nowhere. I actually had my own version of python, numpy, ipython and a couple other packages from source (although numpy wasn't optimized with Lapack or Atlas). I needed h5py, so I got szip and hdf5 from source and installed them and got them up and going. H5py was still complaining and I couldn't find any .so libraries it was looking for (I think I needed to download the development hdf5 and maybe I didn't, still confused about this one). Well, I tried to start over from scratch. Now I'm not even able to install python-2.7 from source.
I run "./configure --prefix=/u/myusername/local" and then "make install" and I get this error:

```
/opt/cray/xt-asyncpe/4.5/bin/cc -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
Modules/python.o \
libpython2.7.a -lresolv -ldl -lutil -lm
pgcc-Error-Unknown switch: -Xlinker
pgcc-Error-Unknown switch: -export-dynamic
make: *** [python] Error 1
```

If I do an "export CC=/usr/bin/gcc" and then repeat the last two steps I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes Parser/acceler.o        Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o Parser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Objects/obmalloc.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/pyctype.o Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o Parser/printgrammar.o Parser/pgenmain.o -lpthread -ldl -lutil -o Parser/pgen
Parser/tokenizer_pgen.o: In function `.st7206':
tokenizer_pgen.c:(.data+0x308): undefined reference to `__pgdbg_stub'
Parser/printgrammar.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `__pgdbg_stub'
Parser/pgenmain.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `__pgdbg_stub'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Parser/pgen] Error 1
```

NOTE: If I do an "export CC=/usr/bin/cc" and use this cc instead I get the same error that I do with gcc.

So, in a nutshell I'm completely frustrated and lost... google hasn't been able to help me out. I know I'm asking a lot of questions but if anyone could help I'd be eternally grateful.

Thanks in advance and for your time.

Comment: It's not really a programming question ... Maybe consider asking on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: The second set of errors looks to be because you have some object files compiled with the portland compiler and are trying to mix them with gcc. Make sure the whole build is cleaned of objects before changing compilers.